# Axios error 401 message pops up in app before trying refresh token in axios interceptor

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios

AxiosConfig.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import { store } from "./redux/store";
import { login, logout } from "./redux/slices/user";

const baseURL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL;

axios.defaults.baseURL = baseURL;

export const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    accept: "application/json",
  },
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  async (error) => {
    const originalRequest = error?.config;
    if (error?.response?.status === 401 && !originalRequest.sent) {
      originalRequest.sent = true;
      const response = await axios.get("/auth/refresh", {
        withCredentials: true,
      });
      if (response.error.status === 403) {
        store.dispatch(logout());
      }
      store.dispatch(login({ user: response.data.user }));
      return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

VerifyJwt.js

```
export const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const accessToken = req.cookies.accessToken;
    if (!accessToken)
      return res.status(403).json({
        message: "Not authenticated, no token provided",
      });
    jwt.verify(accessToken, process.env.ACCESS_SECRET_KEY, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err)
        return res.status(401).json({
          message: "Not logged in, invalid token",
        });
      req.user = decoded.id;
      next();
    });
  } catch (e) {
    res
      .status(500)
      .json({ message: "Something went wrong while verifying jwt" });
  }
};
```

routes/video.js

```
import express from "express";
import { unAuthVerify, verifyToken } from "../middlewares/verifyJwt.js";
import {
  deleteVideo,
  dislikeVideo,
  getVideoDetails,
  getVideos,
  likeVideo,
  updateVideo,
  uploadVideo,
} from "../controllers/videos.js";

const router = express.Router();
router.get("/", getVideos);
router.post("/", verifyToken, uploadVideo);
router.get("/:id", unAuthVerify, getVideoDetails);
router.put("/:id", verifyToken, updateVideo);
router.delete("/:id", verifyToken, deleteVideo);
router.put("/like/:id", verifyToken, likeVideo);
router.put("/dislike/:id", verifyToken, dislikeVideo);

export default router;
```

RefreshToken.js

```
export const refreshToken = async (req, res) => {
  const refreshToken = req.cookies.refreshToken;
  try {
    if (refreshToken) {
      jwt.verify(
        refreshToken,
        process.env.REFRESH_SECRET_KEY,
        async (err, decoded) => {
          if (err) {
            return res.status(403).json({
              message: "Invalid token/not logged in",
            });
          }
          const accessToken = jwt.sign(
            { id: decoded.id },
            process.env.ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,
            {
              expiresIn: "1m",
            }
          );
          const foundUser = await db.query(
            "SELECT * FROM channels WHERE id = $1",
            [decoded.id]
          );
          if (foundUser.rows.length <= 0) {
            return res.status(400).json({
              message: "User/Channel not found",
            });
          }
          const { password, ...others } = foundUser.rows[0];
          if (foundUser.rows.length > 0) {
            res.cookie("accessToken", accessToken, {
              httpOnly: true,
              secure: true,
            });
            return res.status(200).json({
              user: others,
            });
          }
        }
      );
    } else {
      return res.status(403).json({
        message: "Invalid token/not logged in",
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500).json({
      message: "Something went wrong.Please try again",
    });
  }
};
```

Video.jsx

```
const handleLike = async (id) => {
   if (!isLoggedIn) {
     toast.error("You need to login to like a video");
     return;
   }
   if (likedByMe) {
     toast.success("You have already liked this video");
     return;
   }

   try {
     await axiosInstance.put(`/videos/like/${id}`);
     setLikes((prev) => prev + 1);
     if (likedByMe === false) {
       setDisLikes((prev) => prev - 1);
     }
     setLikedByMe(true);
   } catch (e) {
     console.log("Something went wrong while liking video", e);
     toast.error(e.response.data.message);  //I am getting this error first and the app is 
   crashing and only then axios interceptors call refresh token endpoint)
   }
 };
```

I am trying to refresh token in axios interceptor and get new access token. For example, if suppose I try to dislike or like any video and my access token expires at that time, I will get 401 message that token has expired, but I thought before getting this response in client side that is happening inside catch block, axios interceptor  will call refresh token since it is 404 message  and the client will get new access token and then the dislike or like api request will happen again. But in my app, I am getting that error message and it's crashing the app, shouldn't axios interceptor handle it silently? That 404 aunthorized message is getting catched by catch block in client side and errors pops up

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can notice that your route is named `video.js` but you're sending a PUT request to `videos/` (plural). Is that a typo, or that's the cause of your issue?

Comment: actually I have a server.js file where I have appended every request coming to video.js route to '/videos/....' . I don't think that's an issue cause once I am logged in I can successfully send like request. Maybe it can be typo too but it only happens once access token expires

Comment: What's the `error?.response?.status` value in your response interceptor? The `data` of undefined means that the rejection error doesn't contain the `response` property, and in your response interceptor you're returning `Promise.reject(error)`. The `error` would only contain a `message` in that case. If that's the case then your issue should be in the `verifyToken` function. Can you tell me what's the status code inside of your response interceptor?

Comment: the error?.response?.status? Is 404 in the interceptor. But I think in verifyJwt.js I have returned 404 which in interceptor gets caught and also that refresh token call inside interceptor happens successfully. I guess client is catching another error that is not 404

Comment: This is weird  what's the execution flow inside of the `verifyToken`? Does it get to the `next()`? Looking at the method it only returns 401, 403 and 500 explicitly. If the `jwt.verify` breaks it'll result in a 500, so I'd think that it does reach the `next()`.